# Why $\mathbb E[S_T\boldsymbol 1_{\{T\leq n\}}]+\mathbb E[S_n\boldsymbol 1_{\{T>n\}}]=\mathbb E[S_{T\wedge n}]$?

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $(S_n)$ a martingale refer to $(X_n)$ and let $T$ a stopping time. Prove that $$\mathbb E[S_{T\wedge n}]=\mathbb E[S_1],$$ where $a\wedge b:=\min\{a,b\}$.

I have proved that

$$\mathbb E[S_1]=\mathbb E[S_T\boldsymbol 1_{\{T\leq n\}}]+\mathbb E[S_n\boldsymbol 1_{\{T>n\}}]$$

but then, I don't understand why
$$\mathbb E[S_T\boldsymbol 1_{\{T\leq n\}}]+\mathbb E[S_n\boldsymbol 1_{\{T>n\}}]=\mathbb E[S_{T\wedge n}\boldsymbol 1_{\{T\leq n\}}]+\mathbb E[S_{T\wedge n}\boldsymbol 1_{\{T>n\}}].$$

Comment: Simply because $$S_T\boldsymbol 1_{\{T\leq n\}}+ S_n\boldsymbol 1_{\{T>n\}}=S_{T\wedge n}=S_{T\wedge n}\boldsymbol 1_{\{T\leq n\}}+S_{T\wedge n}\boldsymbol 1_{\{T>n\}}.$$

Comment: That's right, thanks a lot :-)